# Pass command line arguments from Form

Tags: php, command

I have a PHP script which contains the following line in the beginning of its script:

```
$file=$argv[$argc-1];
```

In the above line, $file is supposed to represent the file path chosen by the user. I should also point out that in this same PHP page is a Form. The form is a basic one, just has a submit button named "submit" and a text box named "fpath". The Form's layout is as follows:

```
<form method=post action='page1.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

So, basically what I need to accomplish is to pass a command line argument to the current page (page1.php).

How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Thank you,

Evan

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_POST['key']` to get parameter from a POST form.

For the file, use `$_FILES`

For example:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Comment: I understand that I can use POST to get the values from a form, however I was curious how I could pass and retrieve command line arguments between pages.

Comment: Pages send information via Get or Post not "command line". Are you using PHP without web?